# svn diff with DirDiff

Tags: svn, vim

I had used [DirDiff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102) with Mercurial.  I'm now using svn with the new company I work at.  I managed to get vimdiff to work using [this](https://github.com/c4rlo/Subversion-scripts/blob/master/svndiff_helper).  However, it opens up a separate vimdiff for each file and I have to look at the diffs serially.  I pine for the days when I was able to view the entire set of diffs using DirDiff.  Has someone gotten dirdiff working with svn?  If so, please improve the quality of my life and share how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the replacement for the entire set of dirdiff options, but you can try my [aurum](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum) plugin which supports subversion. It can do the following:

- Use “[AuVimDiff](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/aurum.txt.html#:AuVimDiff) full” to get vimdiffs between current working directory and BASE opened in a number of tabs. By default only modified files are opened, but you can also open added and removed ones (one of the windows in these tabs will be empty in this case). AuVimDiff does not require any temporary directories, though temporary files are used in a number of places (because `system()` can’t be used to reliably get arbitrary data).
- Use [AuRecord](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/aurum.txt.html#:AuRecord) to pick changes you want to commit. It is not similar to mercurial “hg record”: instead you get a status window open beyond a split. When you press A in status window changes to the file are <s>included</s> marked for inclusion, when R they are removed, when O you get them opened in the above split: unchanged (or previously edited) version at the left and changed on the right. Left version will be committed, but do not forget to do `:w`.

  Though interface is different from hg record, AuRecord uses the same approach for committing partial changes: original file is moved to {path}.orig and restored after you are done. It will work for any VCS that has “vcs cat”, “vcs status” and “vcs commit” or their equivalents (currently all three supported VCSes have these).

Feel free to file bug reports on the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum/issues), I did not use subversion driver for a real work, only in tests.